# Player rotating in circles(around itself)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, game-development, quaternions

I have a problem: I have a player that has third and first person camera, and I have a problem when I try to rotatate my player in first person, the current way I'm applying my rotate method, my player keeps rotating in circles, I want to fix this issue.

```
void ApplyMovement()
{
    Vector3 currentDirection = playerCamera.DirectionToMoveByCamera(direction);
    controller.Move(currentDirection * currentSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
}

void ApplyRotation()
{
    if (movement2D.sqrMagnitude == 0) return;

    if (playerCamera.PlayerShouldRotateByCameraAngle && !playerCamera.isFirstPerson)
    {
        Debug.Log("sssssss");
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0.0f, playerCamera.cameraTransform.transform.eulerAngles.y, 0.0f);
    }
    else
    {
        float targetAngle = Mathf.Atan2(direction.x, direction.z) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        float angle = Mathf.LerpAngle(transform.eulerAngles.y, targetAngle, smoothTime * Time.deltaTime);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0.0f, angle, 0.0f);
    }
}

public Vector3 DirectionToMoveByCamera(Vector3 direction)
{
    if (PlayerShouldRotateByCameraAngle && !isFirstPerson)
    {
        return Quaternion.AngleAxis(cameras[currentIndex].transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y, Vector3.up) * direction;
    }
    if(isFirstPerson)
    {
        Vector3 movementDirection =cameraTransform.transform.forward* direction.z + cameraTransform.transform.right * direction.x;
        movementDirection.y = 0;
        return movementDirection;
    }

    return direction;

}
```

if I try this line `transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0.0f, playerCamera.cameraTransform.transform.eulerAngles.y, 0.0f);` my player will rotate around itself without moving.

Also `playerCamera` is my class where the `DirectionToMoveByCamera` is at,`playerCamera.CameraTransform` is the object of my main camera which is currently the first person view

[image]